# Power supply circuit explanation/conjectures

Tags: power-supply, pcb

I have a small label-maker; it runs off 8 AA batteries (i.e., about 12V) or (supposedly) a 9.5VDC power brick with a tubular connector with + on the outside.

It won't work with just the power brick, but with batteries it does OK. I dug it open, figuring I might be able to see what was going on, and found the power-supply board, which also happens to have a USB-A connector on it, leading to four wires elsewhere in the device, and unrelated to the power supply.

Here's the circuit I managed to trace:
[image: Battery is 12V; pin2 of jack is +9.5V; pin3 is 0V]

I may have the Zener oriented backwards, and the inductor L1 is just a tiny unlabelled vertical cylinder so I have no idea of its inductance. T1 consists of 3 turns on each side, around a ferrite core. I'm guessing that L1, T1, and C1 are trying to filter out residual AC from the low-budget power brick.

D2 looks like a basic diode, so good for 0.7V drop, which means that if the batteries are fresh, this should produce an output of something like 11.3 V from batteries, but considerably less from the 9.5V power brick.

**Does this make any sense to anyone?** My best guess is that the power brick should really be 12V. And I'm baffled by why the upper coil of L1 seems to route around the resistor/diode pair.

I've also got a photo of the parts, with the traces from the board overlaid on them, in case that's of any use:

[image]

Thoughts?

====
Post-comment addition: it looks as if the power-brick socket has three pins that incorporate some kind of switch-like function, which I've tried to indicate in this revised diagram, but I may well have gotten things a bit wrong in there. Anyhow, the key thing is that pin 2 isn't connected to anything when the power brick is plugged in:

[image]

Comment: What is it that tells you a 9.5 VDC brick is appropriate? Did you get the label maker with the adapter included and was the package unopened and new at the time? Or was it supplied with the maker, but separately, so that it may have been a 'replacement' of some kind? Is there a nameplate on the maker that specifies clearly 9.5 VDC? (Also, it looks as though "L1" is a dead short, from the picture. But I may be mis-reading.) Finally, there's no need for common mode T1 for a battery.

Comment: Great photo. I wish that capability was around forty years ago when I spent my evenings flipping circuit boards over while tracing out the circuits to reverse engineer them. Are you sure you have the pinout for J1 right? Is there a switch contact in there?

Comment: @periblepsis: the 9.5V, center-conductor-negative, is marked on the outside of the labelmaker. OTOH, the power brick that was supplied (this was an Ebay purchase) is only 9V, which may explain something.

Comment: @Transistor: Great question about the pinout. I copied from a similar-looking one I found on Digikey, but you're right: With the plug removed, pins 1 and 3 are connected, and 2 is not. With the plug inserted, the positive pole of the plug is connected to pin 1, and the negative to pin 2, with pin 3 not connected to anything as far as I can tell with my multimeter (which decided to a bit wonky on me just now, alas). I'll edit to reflect this.

Comment: Good work. CircuitLab doesn't have a jack symbol. You'll need to improvise with a switch / arrow combination. (Note the SNAP option on the arrow symbol.)

Comment: @John Yes. It may be a diode drop below 9 V isn't sufficient. I have a huge box (I'm a stupid pack rat) of old and new DC and AC bricks. So I'd probably just grab out something at 10 VDC and try it. (I probably have 9.5 VDC, 10 VDC, 11 VDC, and lots of 12 VDC in that box. Some more reliable than others.) However, for testing purposes I'd just use a standard DC regulated power supply from Tektronix or TekPower and adjust the voltage upwards until things worked. (Current limiting is built in, of course.)

Comment: I've got that same box full of bricks...but none of them is 10 or 11V, alas. I don't have a regulated power supply, but I *do* have some DC/DC converters with adjustable outputs and a 2A limit, which is almost as good as "current limiting". :)

Comment: Problem solved! a 12V 2A power brick was all that was needed. At 10V, it would turn on and let me enter stuff to print, but didn't have the oomph needed to actually run the motor/print head. At 12V, it works like a champ. Perhaps the marking on the lid was left over from an earlier model. :( Thanks, folks.

Comment: @John Done and done, then. Feel free to write up your own answer and then select it. That closes things out and holds the question, I believe, for others to find.